# Logging user presence status discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to log presence for my bot called Timer Bot. I want it to alert everyone when he goes online and when he goes offline. Here is the script I'm using -

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let member = newPresence.member;
    // User id of the user you're tracking status.
    if (member.id === '603517534720753686') {
        if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
            // Your specific channel to send a message in.
            let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('788547135234375712');
            // You can also use member.guild.channels.resolve('<channelId>');

            let text = "";

            if (newPresence.status === "online") {
                text = "**Hello @everyone, Timer Bot is now online! Thank you for your patience.**";
            } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
                text = "**@everyone Due to issues, Timer Bot is currently offline. We apologize for the inconvenience.**";
            }
            // etc...

            channel.send(text);
        }
    }
});
```

For some reason, it doesn't work. Anyone know why?
Thanks,
Brian.#1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable presence intent and then pass it in to the client when logging in.

[image]

[image]

```js
new Discord.Client({ws:{intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES]}});
```

Source: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS
https://discord.com/developers/applications/